# Minecraft can't join LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

My sister and I are trying to start a LAN server. It worked fine yesterday, but today it is not working anymore. Each time she tries to log in it says:

`java.net.connectException:Connection refused: no further information.`

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Are you making a Server using a dedicated Server .jar file? Or are you just opening one of your worlds to LAN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: According to the linked question, it might be a Firewall issue. You can try turning it off temporarily (albeit this might încur a security problem).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as a mater of fact I do. It is a weird glitch but only PROXY servers can work when it comes to LAN servers. The reason why you could connect before may be because it was another update. Also, you might need to reinstall minecraft on BOTH computers. This sometimes works for people. You might also be on different versions of Minecraft when trying to connect. I would look at videos on youtube to try and find the answer. Other than that, you might just not have all computer drivers up to date on one computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use LogMein Hamachi, set Online mode to false and put the IPV4 from Hamachi to ServerProperties and if this don't work then turn off the Firewall.