# How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am getting the following error when I try to connect to a Minecraft server:

[image: Connection refused: no further information]

This is all servers, not just one.

The error says:

> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information:
>
> Version 1.12

I've tried:

- Restarting Minecraft
- Restarting Computer
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Mincraft
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Java
- Altering Firewall
- Restarting Internet
- I've messed with my port, made a second windows account, reset netsh winsock
- Checked hosts
- Made a new WINDOWS account

The overlay in the bottom right is Geforce's Overlay for game capturing. I don't have any mods installed.

A Mojang support ticket wouldn't help. Im desperate.

Comment: Could you add the results of a traceroute in terminal/command prompt (to the IP address of a minecraft server) along with a launcher log of the error? (To get the full launcher logs, open the launcher to start the game and go to settings and enable "Keep Launcher open when game is running" and "open output log when the game starts." Then, launch the game, try to connect to server, and copy the log output.)

Comment: Windows CMD -> `ipconfig /flushdns` or try using a different/public DNS server (network -> properties -> ip v4 -> properties)... easy to do and sometimes it helps.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10?

Comment: I was finally able to connect to my Minecraft server (using the IPv4 Address) by allowing all Java apps and the 1.15.2.jar file through my firewall. Plus don't forget you have to start up your Minecraft server (clicking n the run.bat or server.jar files) prior to connecting to the server in Minecraft Multiplayer mode! After restarting my computer many times I sometimes forget I have to restart the Minecraft server too.  :-)

Comment: I have disabled firewall on both computers (client and host) and get this error. Before, the connection would just time out.  It seems like this might be firewall related after all, but if the firewall is truly off on both machines, why is it refusing to connect?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same error on my local network, it looks like a firewall issue on the host/server side. For me, to troubleshoot I used [nmap](https://nmap.org/). The LAN game showed up in multiplayer as 10.0.0.21:49299. nmap reported that port from that IP as closed/filtered; i.e. a firewall issue.

To confirm it is a firewall issue, [turn off the firewall](https://www.howtogeek.com/242375/how-to-troubleshoot-minecraft-lan-game-problems/) (momentarily). See if you're able to connect while the firewall is disabled.

Comment: AVG Business was blocking it for me, standard AVG let it through fine :-) Still working out how to add rule for it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it has something to do with Firewall **not** allowing traffic to the 1.12.jar file located in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\versions(version).

I assume that when you say you have "Altered the Firewall" you mean that you *only* allowed connections to the Java.exes but **NOT** the actual 1.12.jar file itself.

> **Important:** When creating the rule it is important to make sure these configurations are set: Set the program path to the 1.12.jar file, and make sure to
>   check "Allow the Connection" when configuring the rule.