# Minecraft Server Failed to connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux, hosting, networking

I'm trying to set up a Minecraft server on a CentOS 7 VM so that my friends and I can play. I've been following a guide on how to set it up and was able to make it all the way through until the actual connecting to the server part.

I've made sure there is a port exception for 25565, and when I use `ss -natu` it shows the the port is listening for a connecting from java... though every time I try to connect I keep getting the `io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception connection timed out error`.

Not sure if I don't have the firewalld set up properly or if something else is the matter.

Comment: Are you sure that the port forwarding works the same when using a VM? It might not appear as its own device in your router, in that case you might only grant access to the host system, not the VM.

Comment: Sometimes the port forwarding on a VM may not be seen through the host machine. You can check quickly by performing a test with tools like canyouseeme. If the tool can see the server then the firewall is setup correctly. If not, then the firewall is an issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: I thought this would have been part of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft), but no. Should it be added?

Comment: @Joachim its quite common of an error, but there is another dedicated post we often point to (as pppery linked).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using bridged or NAT mode on your VM?  Also, on CentOS, SELinux may be preventing you from connecting.  Check out [this link](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-use-selinux-port-labelling/) for instructions on how to work around that.