# "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

So I have been hosting my own Minecraft server for me and some friends for a while and everything has been working fine for the longest time. However, in the past week I have been having a problem.
The problem is that no one can connect to the server and when someone tries to it says "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information"

The server is 1.12.2

Things I have tried are:
Restarting Minecraft
Restarting Computer
Uninstalling and Reinstalling Mincraft
Uninstalling and Reinstalling Java
Altering Firewall
Restarting Internet
I've messed with my port

There are no mods only 3 plugins
ClearLag
SetHome
WorldEdit
They are all up to date. Please someone help me, my Mojang support ticket didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Answer (score -1):

A "connection timed out" issue is one of the most frustrating to try to fix...

It could be:

- Client-side issues (as it's affecting everyone, and they were fine before, this is unlikely, but possible)
- A lack of allocated memory to the server causing it to be too busy doing other things to deal with player logins.
- Some other software running on your server, draining resources such as CPU or bandwidth
- Your firewall settings may have changed on your server.
- Mojang's own servers may having problems (check [MojangStatus on Twitter](https://twitter.com/MojangStatus) and a [server status site](https://mcsrvstat.us) )
- Your router settings changed/updated, causing port-forwarding rules to be lost - check those.