# Problems connecting to my Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have openend a minecraft server for my friends and I, but I have an issue. Anyone with a different IP can connect (tested by connecting via Mobile Data Tethering on my phone), but anyone with the same public IP address as the server cannot connect (tested on different computers/ports with different IPs (such as public IP and the server's IP)) (if it's any use, the error when I try to connect is: *io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information*). I have tried restarting the router, as well as the server and I have no different outcomes (and yes, I do have my server open).

Note: I did read similar posts to mine, but none of them seemed to be able to help me out.

Comment: See if this helps -- <https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you managed to get multiple computers with the same IP address (it's certainly possible, but unlikely to happen accidentally), but that is very likely the issue. IP addresses are used to select which computer to send a package to via the internet, so your two computers might get packages they didn't request and not know how to handle them or they might not get packages that they requested and either wait for them forever or show an error message.

You should never have two computers with the same IP address connected to the same network (like the internet), this will always lead to various issues, some of them might be very hard to debug.

Comment: BTW, the same applies to entity UUIDs in Minecraft. If you have multiple entities with the same ID, strange stuff can happen.

Comment: I am indeed aware to not connect multiple computers to the same IP, I meant they are on the same public IP (the one you get by searching "my ip" on google)

Comment: Maybe we mean different things. Do you get the same result on https://www.wieistmeineip.de/ on both computers? If yes, you have done something wrong, or at least, in a way I would not recommend.

Comment: The thing is, that's not my doing, thats my ISP's settings. Every single device connected to my internet has that public IP (phones, computers, TVs). I don't think I did anything wrong, as that's what a public IP is supposed to be(according to Wikipedia), but I'm not a networking pro either, so i don't know.

Comment: Then you should complain to them. That should really not happen.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I mean. Every computer has to connect to the ISP, which assigns me a public IP address. That IP adress is supposed to be shared by all computers, as the computers themselves have their own IP address (192.168.x.y). When I say Public IP, I mean the one that is supposed to be shared by all computers.

Comment: No IP address is ever supposed to be shared by multiple computers, that's pretty much the point of IP addresses. Some companies have rare exceptions, for example 8:8:8:8 could reach one of multiple servers owned by Google that are spread out over the world. But in that case there is a complicated system of measures in place to make sure that it still works. It is definitely not something for regular home computers.