# Friends unable to connect to Minecraft Server: Connection Refused

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

I am creating a  modded forge minecraft server v 1.12.2, but my friend on a **different** network than mine cannot join. Here is the error he gets: `io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception: connection refused`

Here are some things I have done so far:

- Set my PC's IP to a static one
- Port forwarded my static IP with port 25565 (TCP/UDP)
- Disabled all firewalls on my PC (the one running the server, also tried having my friend disable his)
- Allowed the 25565 port through windows firewall by adding inbound/outbound rules (even though its disabled...)
- My friend is using my public Ipv4 (did not try public ipv6, it gives a long weird string of chars, and i've never connected to a server like this)
- tried connecting with just the ip, and ip:port methods.
- Tried using a laptop I own to connect to the server (using my phone's hotspot data) to simulate a different computer joining from a different network. It also gave the same error.
- **I can connect to the server on the host PC fine, the server starts up**
- when checking *canyouseeme.org* with my public ipv4 and the port 25565, it says "I could not see your service on ___ on port 25565. Reason: Connection Timed Out"
- I do not have any third part antivirus apps or anything of the sort installed (that i know of).
- also did not specify a server ip in the properties file of the server

I am not sure what to do now, and I am not sure why canyouseeme.org says the port is not open. I had the server running when I checked this.

Are there any other diagnostic tests I can do? The only thing I am not sure of is my static IP. I have it set to stay on whatever my PC was on at the time (ie. it is set to be an ip that is in the possible ranges of dynamic IPs on my network). I'm not sure if this is a problem, but I saw it mentioned once somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Answer (score 0):

Answer by OP, originally posted in the question body:

---

**UPDATE:**
After spending hours on this issue, driving myself nuts because everything *should* have been working, I decided to check my router port forwarding settings one last time.

It somehow did not save my most recent IP change (changing from 198.162.0.13 to 0.11, it stayed at 0.13). I changed it to the correct IP... and this solved the issue (I can connect from my second PC on my phone's network.)

**tl;dr:** always triple check that you port forwarded everything properly...