# How can I connect to a LAN server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My sister and I are trying to play Minecraft together, but no matter what we try, we can't get it to work. We've had this problem numerous times in the past, and it's always stopped us from playing together, unless on servers like Hypixel. We've spent the last two hours trying to fix this and reading/watching tutorials, but nothing has helped. When I try to connect, I have to do direct connect because it will not show the world automatically, despite us playing on the same IP and same version. It gives me the error message `io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information.` I've tried turning off the firewall, but that doesn't do anything. What should I do?

Comment: Are you on the same WiFi?

Comment: Yeah, we're on the same wifi.

Comment: The term LAN server is unclear. Are you talking about a dedicated server or a singleplayer world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is Hamachi.

Download Hamachi on your PC, Register in the app. Then create a new Network (With any name and password). Tell the name and password to your sister, so that she can join. After she did it, she must copy your IP address (it is shown in Hamachi).

Then you just enter your world and open it to LAN. Tell your sister the PORT, which is shown in the chat.

She will have to go to Multiplayer/Direct Connect  and paste the IP and PORT together.

Here is the example of how it should look like:

12.34.56.78:57436

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the local IP of the host computer into Direct Connect in Multiplayer.

To find your local IP, there are two different ways:

On Windows, press the Windows button, usually next to alt or control. Then type `cmd` and you should see Command Prompt show up. Open that up and you should see a black rectangle with the directory in it.

Type `ipconfig` into it.

Look for something like:

`IPv4 Address.. 192.168.0.295`

or something similar. Write that IP down.

When you start a LAN world in Minecraft, you might see something like this in chat:

`LAN world started on port 12345`

12345, meaning a 5 digit code.

Now that you have the IP and port, you can connect to the world.

On the visitor computer, go to Direct Connect in multiplayer, and type the IP and port seperated by a colon. Like this:
`192.168.0.295:12345`.

Click Connect and you should join the world!

Now for Mac, it's a pretty similar process.

To find your IP address:

1. Click on the WiFi menu button in your Mac's menu bar.
2. Then select Network Preferences.

[image: Network preferences]

3. Select your network.
4. Then click on the Advanced button.

[image: Advanced button]

5. Next, click the TCP/IP tab.
6. Your computer’s IP address will be a series of numbers next to IPv4 Address.

And then put the IP and port next to each other seperated by a colon.
`192.168.1.295:12345`.

And that's it!

I hope this helped and have a nice day!