# Unable to join some servers without a VPN

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am able to connect to almost every Minecraft server that I have tried, such as Hypixel and some random ones. However, very few have an issue where I get an error on connect. "io.netty.channel.... Connection refused: no further information." When trying a VPN, I am able to connect just fine. However, a VPN isn't a good option since many servers have a list of IP's from known VPN's to prevent entry to the server. Does anyone know a fix to the problem?

https://streamable.com/eeadk7 In the video here it shows that I can not connect with a VPN. With one, I am able to connect. The kick saying no VPN's allowed means I have connected, just was kicked in the login event. This happens on Optifine 1.8.8 and the latest release, 1.16.3.

Comment: Make sure your router allows these connections

Comment: Since you can't connect normally but can connect with a VPN, that makes me wonder if your IP address is blocked in the servers that are refusing your connection.

Comment: @Sciborg Never even joined the server before, and it happens on multiple so very unlikely.

Comment: @Penguin How should I go about this? I can join any other servers, just not a select few

Comment: @Itzdlg i was more asking like is it your/your parents' router?

Comment: @Penguin Parents' router, however I have access to the physical router & to the admin web panel

Comment: @Itzdlg so if its your own private router they shouldn’t be blocked. Go to CMD and ping a server that isn’t working. I will use Hypixel as an example. Put: `ping hypixel.net` then see if you get a response. This will allow us to narrow it down. If you get a response then something must be wrong with the Minecraft client.

Comment: @Penguin Sorry for the late response, running `ping <server ip>` gave me a "Ping request could not find host <ip>. Please check the name and
try again." However, with a VPN, I get the same result. The only difference is that I can connect to the server

Comment: @Itzdlg hmm... I don't really no how to help you. This is a weird situation, as if your computer can't ping the server I don't know how it works in Minecraft. Sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)