# Minecraft Server| When I try to join my minecraft server using direct connect, why do I get an error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

Essentially, I've set up a minecraft server but I am unable to join my own because I get the error:
`io.netty.channed.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`
Here are some of the things I've done:

- connected with direct connect with only my IP
- connected with direct connect with my IP and port
- allowed the firewall to give access to javaw

I have seen another question similar to this but the comments/replies didn't make sense to me at all
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me all the time. some things to try is to restart minecraft, reload the server page, copy and paste the server address again, try rebooting the server, and last of all, try using the other method besides direct connect.

Comment: What method usually works to fix it?