# Fixing "io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$AnnotatedConnectExeption: Conection timed out: no further information" in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I had this problem for some time and even after 4 months of trying to solve it, I couldn't manage to overcome my issue. Whenever I try to log in to my Minecraft Server I get the `io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$AnnotatedConnectExeption: Connection timed out: no further information` Error. The problem is clearly server-sided because on any other server I can log in just fine, but on my own, I can't. My first thought was that the problem might be from my computer, but when I asked my friend to join the server he received the same message. To be clear the server is running on a separate computer from the one I tried to join. When I tried to log from the localhost(IP:0) it still showed the same message so I can clearly see that the issue is server-sided. I personally tried every single method I found on the internet to fix my issue, but none seemed to work. I even tried to disable my firewall on the router and on the computer. And it still doesn't fix the issue.

The server is running on paper 1.16.4 with the following plugins installed: Multiverse-Core-4.2.2, Multiverse-Portals-4.2.1, Multiverse-NetherPortals-4.2.1, Multiverse-SignPortals-4.2.0, LuckPerms-Bukkit-5.2.54, worldedit-bukkit-7.2.0, ViaBackwards-3.2.0, ViaVersion-3.2.0 and has java 8 installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: Nope, I already tried that U_U

Comment: Are you able to connect if you disable all your plugins?