# How Do I Fix This Minecraft Error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So recently, I got a Minecraft account and wanted to play with my sister but my sister has a demo account. So I used LAN connection but every time I connect to the LAN server it comes up with io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information:
And I need a solution. I used direct connect and entered this: (IP HIDDEN):(PORT)
I've tried:
Restarting Minecraft
Disabling Firewall on my sister's device
Disabling all VPN's
Tried multiple times

Device Specs:
My Computer:
Windows 10 Mac Book Pro
Using Minecraft 1.16.5 Vanilla

Sister's Computer:
MacOS Big Sur Mac Book Air
Using Minecraft 1.16.5 Vanilla Demo
[image]

Comment: Can you `ping` the other computer? (Open Terminal / Command Prompt and type `ping [IP Address]`)

Comment: By 'demo account' do you mean that your sister does not have a bought copy of Minecraft? Unless you pay the 26 dollars USD, you cannot use any multiplayer features or play on any single player seed except the demo seed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: @aytimothy I will try that.

Comment: @ScythePhantom Yea. Demo means that the account isn't bought. But you can still open to LAN though. So how would you solve this?

Comment: @npoka Strange. A demo account should not be able to Open To Lan. When you press the Open To Lan button does it let you turn on cheats? If you press Start Lan World does it give you a message that says the port the game is hosted on?

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate but neither of the linked questions talk about demo mode. What I am assuming to be the problem is that your sibling does not have a fully bought version of Minecraft and there is no way to use any multiplayer features with a demo account.