# Can't join my server: "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I used to be able to connect to my bukkit server in Minecraft by my IP address, but after a while, I could not. It gives me this error when I try to join my server:

> Failed to connect to the server
>
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

[image]

I know that my IPv4 address is `192.168.1.105`, and I put this in the "server.properties" file.

[image]
[image]

When I click on the run.bat file, the server turns on, but I am not able to join it with my IP address, (I can just join with IP4 address).

And Here are my port forwarding settings:

[image]

Here is firewall setting:

[image]

**TIP: I can just join my server using the IPv4 address (`192.168.1.105`)**,
but me and my friends can't join with my IP address. How do I resolve this problem?

**EDITED:**

I changed my modem and tried again and it worked completly! However, when I connect to another modem, I am not able to connect to my server

Comment: Can we have your full logs? Also unfortunately, technical support is not permitted here. It'd make sense you'll get a "no server on the other side" error if you server failed to start in the first place. Your error only means [Logger cannot output](https://github.com/komoot/photon/issues/394) [to the Command Prompt/Console](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/2982167-error-unable-to-inject-fields-into-builder-class), though that shouldn't cause your server to not run at all.

Comment: Thanks @aytimothy,  heare are my last logs: https://mega.nz/file/RTYSkTZQ#_VQOxqXzKl20UEZGoFYjdDRP-3iuoWBEezfjLlKbFZU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: Thanks @gnemlock, I want my friends to be able to join the server too, so I have to make the server with the my IP address, Currently the server only opens with my IP4 address and my friends are not able to join my server

Comment: Re: _my friend can't join with this IP address_, `192.168.1.105` is a local address. They will need to connect using your external IP address, which you can find with sites such as https://whatismyip.com

Comment: @Schism, Thanks for the reply, yes I did the same, I just edited the post by mistake I meaen: 

*I can just join my server using the IP4 address (192.168.1.105), but me and my friends can't join with my IP address. How do I resolve this problem?*

Answer (score 4):

**You are providing your friends with the wrong IP address. Follow these instructions to retrieve your *global* IP address, and ask them to connect with that.**

*Disclaimer: This answer comes from having absolutely no knowledge of Minecraft what so ever. From what you have led me to understand, you're issue stems from core networking issues, so this should apply to Minecraft just as it would to any other server you were trying to set up.*

---

### First, let's make sure we are on the same page.

1. You have a Minecraft server with the IP address of `192.168...`.
2. You are on the same network as this server. It is your own computer, or it is otherwise running on a computer within your house.
3. You are able to connect to the server.
4. Your friends are trying to connect from outside your house.
5. Your friends are not able to connect to the server.

### You are providing a local IP address

The address you provide is explicitly used to identify a local device. That means I could use it to connect to your server *when I am in your house and connected to your network*. As soon as I have to connect using the Internet, that address means nothing.

### You need to use a global IP address

Never fear; your server already has one of these, and it is pretty easy to retrieve. All you need to do is google "what is my IP address" from the same computer. Google will tell you what it is. Copy it down. Try using that IP address to connect to your server.

***Do not tell us what that address is. Make sure that the person in charge of the network gives you permission to provide this address to other people.*** Providing this IP address to *anyone* could be a serious security risk, even if you know them.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time and response, I got my IP exactly the same way, and when I gave it to my friends or tested it myself, I was not able to connect to my server. I got this error: 

>>io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information @gnemlock

Comment: I can connect to my server only by connecting with IP4 address not global IP address

Comment: Worth noting, Google is inadequate if you have IPv6 support, you'll need to use a service like https://www.whatismyip.com/ (no affiliation) to get your IPv4 instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that my ip4 address is: 192.168.1.105 and I put this in "server.properties" file.

Don't. Leave your `server-ip` to   (blank). Your server will just bind to your local address and nobody externally will be able to access it. (Depending on your configuration, `localhost` won't work either)

> [I can connect to my server only by connecting with IP4 address not global IP address](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387089/i-can-not-start-my-minecraft-bukkit-server-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelann#comment545641_387091)

The above is why. Also, check your firewall and make sure Java is allowed to be communicated from the outside.

[@Gnemlock's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387091/75275) regarding IP address is also a good read too.

Your computer usually has two addresses; a local (192.X.X.X or 10.X.X.X*) and a global address is usually anything other than the above in a single-layer network (means your router is connected straight to the phone line; multi-layered networks are usually only seen in corporate environments) shared between all devices on your home network.

When someone outside of your house needs to connect to use, they use the public address. When something within your home needs to talk to each other, you use the local address.

*some older modems remaps 10.0.0.X to local devices.

Comment: Multilayered networks are becoming increasingly common as CGNAT gets more common. ISPs can't get IPv4 addresses to serve all their customers, so residential customers aren't always guaranteed to get a public IP depending on which ISP you are talking about.

Comment: Also, plenty of the space in 128-223 /8s is allocated to ISPs through the RIRs so could be used in residential IPs, not just below 127.

Comment: It's massively simplified, please don't turn this into [su]

Comment: @aytimonthy, If you want to simplify, then just don't mention multilayered vs single layered. Corporate networks really aren't relevant. CGNAT potentially is. And 1-127 vs 1-223 is not really a difference of complexity, its just a number.

Comment: Please edit, if you feel you can make an improvement; will do it later if I get the time.

Comment: @aytimothy, Hi, thanks for your explanation, I did not leave the server-ip blank,

I think it's from the firewall to make sure I send a picture see right?: 
>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VJWU.png

*I also edited my question, thank you for reading it again*

Answer (score 0):

You must allow your Windows firewall to open the port on Public and Private networks, for Java, you should have gotten a pop-up asking for that though, if you're not sure, [follow this guide](https://windowscrazy.com/979-how-to-allow-java-through-firewall-windows-10).

Then, get your external IP address, the one that Google or [this](https://ipchicken.com/) gives, and that's the one you give to your friends, you can also try to connect by it on your side which must work, otherwise there's something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I allowed my firewall but it still does not work it is clear in this photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VJWU.png

I also edited my question, thanks for reading again