# Can't join my minecraft server using public ip address | port forwarding problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-bukkit

I had a problem connecting to my Minecraft Bukkit server with the public IP address (I can just join with my IPv4 address):

[In the previous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387089/cant-join-my-server-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexceptio?noredirect=1#comment545655_387089) question I asked, I realized that the problem is with the port forwarding.

I use my Ipv4 address in port forwarding and 25565 port (default port of Minecraft server)

[image]
[image]

The strange thing here is that I tested on two modems with the **same brand** but **different internet service** and only one of them worked with public IP address and the 25565 is open on that modem
**but** In another modem not worked with my public Ip address and I couldn't join my bukkit server but I can join with IPv4 Address (and the 25565 port is close)!!

I know that the 25565 port is closed when I switch to Modem 2:

[image]
[image]

**How can I open that port on Modem 2?**

I searched for a couple of hours but I didn't find a good way

**All I know is that this problem is definitely related to the port  forwarding or modem issues** (I even completely reset the modem and it didn't work!)

> Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does your server show as online using this online checker when you enter your public IP?: https://mcsrvstat.us/

The only reason I ask is because in the past I have set up a server on my PC and was unable to connect using the public IP, but was able to connect using my IPv4 address, however other people WERE able to connect using my public IP.