# Unable to Join Minecraft LAN server [Java 1.17.1]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

I've been trying to connect to my little brother's LAN world so we can play without having to start fresh. I know it's likely a firewall issue on his computer's side because he can join me without issue, but I cannot join him unless I turn off his firewall, which no one should have to do. I made sure we are on the same network, we can ping each other's PCs. I made sure javaw.exe was allowed on both of our PCs, restarted many times. I can even SEE the world on the server list, but I can't connect for some unknown reason with the firewall.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to connect to the world?

Comment: It gives the error "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: [pc-name/ip/port]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)

Comment: Yeah they are having the same issue as me, though I'm not sure how to add the jar for the Minecraft version through the firewall, as someone said on that post, I searched the Minecraft launcher directories and I couldn't find a version jar so that I could allow it past the firewall.