# io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception on Linux Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux, hosting, networking

There are numerous threads on this same issue, which I know because I've read a lot of them, but nothing's worked so far.

I had a Debian modded Minecraft server that ran fine apart from a horrendous tickrate (running AllTheMods 3 Remix and GregTech: New Horizons), so a friend gave me an old computer with better hardware to upgrade it. I took the hard drive out of the old computer and put it into the new one, which I expected to cause problems but none that would take this long to fix.

I get `io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception` whenever I try to connect to the server through a public IP now (local works fine). I have:

- Opened the port 25565 on my router and server computer
- Checked my firewall on the client computer allows the application
- Tried changing settings with iptables
- Tried using wireless connection instead
- Making sure the IP in server.properties is blank
- Checked my Java installation

> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-8u302-b08-1~deb9u1-b08)

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)

I'm 99% sure this is a server problem, I can't recall exactly what I did in iptables so it might be related to the firewall, but I'm out of ideas.

EDIT: I think the problem might be that the port got opened incorrectly somehow, gonna try to change router settings in a bit. Trying to telnet to the server ip with port 25565 couldn't connect either. 25565 shows up at listening while using the `ss -l` command, but `netstat -l` doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: We have a few posts on our site about this error. [Have you checked them out?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=io.netty.channel.abstractchannel%24annotatedconnectexception) One other thing I can think of is trying a completely different port. And lastly, disable all mods and see what happens, though I'm leaning towards that not being the issue since the server runs without crashing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co)